# Manifest.yml empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

Whenever I run `rake assets:precompile`, I get a `manifest.yml` file that looks like:

```
--- {}
```

Something must be going wrong. Here is my output for `rake assets:precompile --trace`:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
```

Can someone help?? Thanks!

### UPDATE:

Feel free to look at my code at [www.github.com/sambaek/novulty](http://www.github.com/sambaek/novulty)

Comment: Having *any* information about your `app/assets`, `lib/assets`, and `vendor/assets` contents would be useful, as well as the value of your application's `YOURAPPLICAION::Application.config.assets.precompile` value.

Comment: sorry for the late response. i added my github repo. hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run `rake assets:precompile` for your application I get the following output

```
➜  novulty git:(master) ✗ rake assets:precompile                     
/Users/deefour/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /Users/deefour/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Undefined variable: "$baseLineHeight".
  (in /Users/deefour/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/gemsets/novulty/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_accordion.scss)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/deefour/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake assets:precompile  12.50s user 1.21s system 99% cpu 13.744 total
```

I'm not sure what your intention is, but you have

- `app/asssets/bootstrap.min.css` being included in `app/assets/application.css`
- `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` in your `Gemfile` which appears to cause `bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_accordion.scss` *(among other files)* to be added to your pipeline even though they're not included in require lines in `app/assets/application.css`

It seems like you have the bootstrap gem included to use it's Javascript plugins, but are trying to omit the SASS files in favor of the hard-coded, minified CSS file?

In any event, the error I get says that the `$baseLineHeight` SASS variable is not defined for a line in that gem file's asset - an asset you otherwise appear to ignore *(from the best I can tell)*.

I then did the following

1. Commented out the `bootstrap-sass` gem in your `Gemfile`

   ```
   #gem 'bootstrap-sass'
   ```
2. Ran `bundle`
3. Ran `rake assets:clean`
4. Removed the following require lines from your `app/assets/application.js` because they were coming from the `bootstrap-sass` gem I removed in **1.** above

   ```
   //= require bootstrap-transition
   //= require bootstrap-button
   //= require bootstrap-carousel
   //= require bootstrap-collapse
   //= require bootstrap-tab
   ```
5. Ran `rake assets:precompile`

This results in the following `public/assets/manifest.yml`.

- https://gist.github.com/d29f70b047c7b0606263

I think you need to either of the following

- Use the `bootstrap-sass` gem as intended. Include the SASS files in your `app/assets/application.css` *(doing this it a bit outside the scope of this question)*
- Get rid of the `bootstrap-sass` gem as I have above, and include the necessary Javascript files as assets in your `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory *(which is where `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css` belongs too - `vendor/assets/stylesheets`)*

Comment: thank you for your help. sorry for responding so late. but you are correct!